# Serve static files over http within an android app with WebView

Tags: android, http, webview

I have a nuxt.js 3 generated javascript app, which is just some html, JS & other assets. My issue is that passing a `file://<path>/index.html` as a url to a web_view means that assets are broken since all addresses are origin-relative, e.g. `/home/index.html`, `/_nuxt/entry.123456.css`, not path-relative like `home/index.html`. (i think it would not work for subpages anyway, being path-relative)

How to overcome this?

1. is there any way to set the web_view to know where to get the static files from? there are no other requests from the web_view other than GETs for static assets & changes of location. I'm thinking something like request interception and rewriting the path or even the response. but that sounds just like a server, so:
2. I guess I'm gonna need a http server. Can you suggest me some simple up-to-date library that can serve files within an android app? Or can you point me to some API from android native toolbox to open a socket and serve static files via http response? Also, will such a server be accessible for other apps, for the whole android device on `localhost`? I would like to avert that; the only consumer of the files should be the web_view.

To avoid obvious counter-question - but why? It's that I intend to build a hybrid android app, that does simply open a web_view full-screen. I am aware of limitations of such solution and I'm fine with that. The android part is where I'm not well experienced. If this gets too over-complicated, I'm gonna just change the way how to produce the js app in the first place. but nuxt.js is my best option for now.

Comment: What do you mean with static files? Just html files?

Comment: I have never heard of 'origin relative' or 'path-relative'. Only about full paths and relative paths.

Comment: Pretty unclear which problem you actually have.

Comment: read "static files" as just "files". with the path/origin relative i mean the fact that the paths start with `/`, so i can't just use `file://` as url for the web_view. both are "relative" url path. @blackapps i guess i just need a http server within an android app.

Comment: If a path starts with a `/` then it is a full path and you can put `file://` before it. If it does not start with a `/` then it is a relative path and you can use it as is as the WebView like any browser will find it.